# Помощь с подсветкой синтаксиса в VS

Tags: visual-studio

При переименовании связанных файлов в проекте и (или) смене расширения файлов (н-р с `.cpp` на `.cc`) моя VS 2022 перестает подсвечивать синтаксис. Как вернуть подсветку?

Что я пробовал:

- Пересобирать проект;
- Перезапускать VS.

Помогает только создание нового элемент и вставка кода туда. Но это какой-то костыль.

В примере ниже я переименовал `Memory.h`.

[image: Пример отсутствия подсветки синтаксиса]

Лог сборки:

```
1>------ Перестроение всех файлов начато: проект: Notepad for OOP, Конфигурация: Debug x64 ------
1>labs.cc
1>Notepad for OOP.vcxproj -> C:\Users\mag1s\Source\Repos\MIREA\x64\Debug\Notepad for OOP.exe
========== Перестроить все: успешно — 1, неудачно — 0, пропущено — 0 ==========
========== Перестроить завершено в 17:49 и заняло 01,592 с ==========
```